# Disallowing line break before dash (en dash and em dash)

Tags: line-breaking, best-practices, punctuation

In Polish typography dash (pol. *myślnik*) should not be put after a line break.
Below you can find badly and correctly typed samples using en dash (pol. *półpauza*) and em dash (pol. *pauza*).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=95mm,paperheight=55mm,margin=5mm,right=24mm,marginparsep=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% line break before a dash is a sin according to Polish typography rules
\leavevmode\marginpar{\textsc{\color{purple}źle\\(bad)}}%
To jest maciupeńki test półpauzy -- na Zachodzie nazywanej \emph{en dash}.  {\color{orange}\hfill~--}
\par \emph{Em dash} za to nazywamy pauzą --- obecnie dość rzadko spotykana. {\color{orange}\hfill~---}
\vfill
% line break after a dash -- this is the way it should be done
\leavevmode\marginpar{\textsc{\color{teal}dobrze\\(good)}}%
To jest maciupeńki test półpauzy~-- na Zachodzie nazywanej \emph{en dash}.  {\color{orange}\hfill~--}
\par \emph{Em dash} za to nazywamy pauzą~--- obecnie dość rzadko spotykana. {\color{orange}\hfill~---}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To obtain correct result I had to use non-breaking space (tie) before each dash.

**Is it possible to fix behavior of all en/em dashes surrounded by normal spaces in LaTeX document?**

*Side note*: I am not asking about workarounds requiring preprocessing, like using `s/ -- /~-- /` in Vim/sed/perl/etc.

Comment: Not in a robust way. The ties are the safest method.

Comment: @egreg: Could you elaborate more on these unhealthy methods? If not as an answer meant to be accepted, then just as bad examples with commentary explaining their badness.

Comment: @przemoc: 1) `En dash` is never surrounded by spaces. It's always surrounded by characters. 2) It's not good to brake neither after `En dash`, nor before it. Better both words, or numbers, before and after the `En dash` to be on the same line. 3) `Em dash` is treated as the `hyphen` not only in polish, but as far as I know, in all European languages.

Comment: @Karl: 1) By normal spaces I meant plain space in .`tex` file, not how they are interpreted, because they should be sometimes shorter than normal spaces. 2) Agree, but breaking after is still acceptable, breaking before is not. 3) Em dash (`---`) is definitely not a hyphen (pol. _dywiz_ or _łącznik_) in Polish! It is `-`. Moreover, if it is used explicitly (like in compound words), it has its own special rule for breaking, because it must be repeated after line break (`\def\dywiz{\kern0sp\discretionary{-}{-}{-}\penalty10000\hskip0sp\relax}` from [polski](http://ctan.org/pkg/polski) package).

Comment: @Karl: Giving more complete answer to 1) depends on the language and usage, i.e. en dash function in current context. En dash can be used e.g. as substitute of [figure dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_dash#Figure_dash) `‒` (U+2012), then there is no space around it. But if it is used as pol. _myślnik_ (in the old days only em dash was used for this purpose) like in my example or in non number only ranges (e.g. 1 stycznia -- 2 lutego [Jan 1 -- Feb 2]), then normal spaces should surround it. I am talking about Polish typography, other countries have their own rules and habits.

Comment: @Karl: In german en-dash is used to separate "thoughts" in a sentence ("Gedankenstrich") and is always surrounded by spaces if it used between words: "foo -- bar". There is no space if a comma or dot follows: "foo --, bar". Breaks before and after the en dash in the first case are ok, in the second case ("--,") the break before should be supressed.

Comment: Does "\XeTeXdashbreakstate=1" help if using XeTeX?

Comment: @Karl: I have never seen an en dash separating words (not ranges) without spaces. Em dash is (often) not surrounded by spaces in English typography, but even here it's not the case for many other languages — for example, you ought to use thin/hair spaces in Russian and Latvian, except for ranges.

Comment: @Karl: Wrt. 1): Even in English writing, many style guides recommend to use an en-dash surrounded by spaces in places where the (American) writer would commonly use an em-dash: _[...] For example, the Canadian The Elements of Typographic Style recommends the spaced en dash – like so – and argues that the length and visual magnitude of an em dash "belongs to the padded and corseted aesthetic of Victorian typography."_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Comment: @morbusg `\XeTeXdashbreakstate` is not involved as the problem is to break or not at *spaces*.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov: Russian and Latvian traditionally had entirely different symbols for dashes and hyphen. @Ulrike Fischer: German DIN is changed many times, so what is tradition, and what is correct... The new standard DIN 5008 suggest hyphen for ranges.

Comment: @Karl: Can you elaborate on "entirely different symbols"? They just use a dash (usually 1 em or 3/4 em wide), in case of Russian — for at least two centuries already. Links on dash form and typesetting (in Russian): http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5 http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/97/ http://www.paratype.ru/help/term/terms.asp?code=85

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way to accomplish the task is to make `-` an active character and define it in such a way that it expands to a minus sign in math mode while, in text mode it looks forward to see whether one or two hyphens follow it and act in consequence.

A possible implementation with the active hyphen is as follows

```
\makeatletter
\def\ah@hyphen{-}
\def\ah@endash{--}
\def\ah@emdash{---}
\catcode`\-=\active
\protected\def-{\ifmmode\ah@hyphen\else\expandafter\ah@check\fi}
\def\ah@check{\@ifnextchar-{\ah@checki}{\ah@hyphen}}
\def\ah@checki#1{\@ifnextchar-{\ah@three}{\ah@two}}

\def\ah@two{\unskip~\ah@endash\space\ignorespaces}
\def\ah@three#1{\unskip~\ah@emdash\space\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

---

There is, however, a way out using Unicode characters. If your document is written in UTF-8 you can say

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{–}{\unskip~--\space\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{—}{\unskip~---\space\ignorespaces}
```

where in line 2 `–` is U+2013 EN DASH and in line 3 `—` is U+2014 EM DASH; using these characters in your source will do what you want. The main problem here is that they are almost indistinguishable from each other in a monospaced font. Just to show them I'll put them in a code box:

```
– U+2013 EN DASH  
— U+2014 EM DASH
```

and here's how they appear in a quotation box:

> – U+2013 EN DASH
>      — U+2014 EM DASH

The rendering on screen depends on the font, of course.

Comment: `– —` <- here they are in monospace font.

Comment: @przemoc - just edited your contribution into the answer...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I thought the idea of showing the dashes as a quote was to make the difference between them visible. As code, they're just as indistinguishable as in the code sample above.

Comment: I moved the active character part in your solution to the front, just to keep things together that belong to one thought.

Comment: @doncherry: I thought the idea was to illustrate just how indistinguishable they were; have I misinterpreted? If so, I'll put it back, with grovelling apologies. Enrico, care to comment?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I think that this version can stand: the "active" character solution seems to work correctly and the "indistinguishable" part is sufficiently informative for making a choice.

Answer (score 6):

Inserting ties manually is still a good option: it doesn't have side effects, it is readable and it is easy to train yourself to always type `~---`.

That said, the [`extdash`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extdash) package provides commands for dashes with non-breaking spaces. With the `[shortcuts]` option the `\---` command is made available and stands for an em-dash with non-breaking space. Space surrounding the dash is also reduced for a better appearance.

Comment: The extash package is great. Note that if you want to forbid newlines after, you need to use instead `\===`. You also have many options, like `nospacearound` to remove the half-space automatically added before/after the dash.