# Automatic non-breaking spaces in proper name initials

Tags: spacing

I need to use non-breaking spaces in proper name initials, e.g.

```
J.~W.~Bush
```

Any way to make LaTeX replace regular spaces with non-breaking ones for such cases? Or would I better preprocess my tex files with some regexp/script?

Comment: A script (or manual fix) is probably a better solution as I don't think this is going to be very easy with TeX.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/disallowing-line-break-before-dash-en-dash-and-em-dash) helped me with spaces before dashes, so I thought somebody could have a similar solution for initials based on @ifnextchar. But that wouldn't be easy indeed.

Comment: I assume this is in the context of a bibliography?  `bibtex` or `biblatex`?

Comment: @cslstr Not only, I need it to be like this everywhere in my document. And I use bibtex.

Comment: Will you then assume that any Capital letter followed by a full stop (.) is part of an initials sequence?  It seems like there may be other cases where you would detect the end of a sentence (ending with a capital letter) that is treated like a name.

Comment: @cslstr That wouldn't be a problem; abbreviations other than personal initials are better with non-breaking spaces, too.

Comment: @AndyK. Nobody knows that better than I.  But there would then be a non-breaking space between these two sentences if this were in your document. .... since "I. But" would be interpreted as a name.  Maybe I'm overthinking this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13719/discussion-between-andy-k-and-cslstr)

Comment: Yes you can do it (similar to the linked question) but dont:-) making dash active so that it can adjust spacing has the potential to break things but it is a well worn path: many babel languages make ascii punctuation characters active to adjust space around them, so by now most packages/documents can cope. If you make space active then you have a real chance of breaking everything. You can make simple examples sort of work but the chance of it working reliably on real documents loading real packages from ctan isn't that great.

Answer (score 8):

I added support for initials to my package [luavlna](https://github.com/michal-h21/luavlna). This package uses `luatex` node processing callbacks for language dependent insertion of non-breaking spaces after one letter words and initials.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[czech, english]{babel}
\usepackage{luavlna}
\preventsinglelang{czech}
\begin{document}
  \preventsingledebugon
D. E. Knuth, Ch. Somebody. \selectlanguage{czech} A. Dvořák, 
name in horizontal box \hbox{Č. Zíbrt}, Ř. Jelen \preventsingleoff C. Někdo, 
\preventsingleon Ř. Jelen, Ch. Josef, CH. Thisworkstoo

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that `Ch` is used as one letter in Czech. If you don't want language sensitive processing, set default language with `\preventsinglelang{languagename}` and rules for given language will be used in the whole document.

You can turn off the processing with `\preventsingleoff` and resume it latter with `\preventsingleon`

`luavlna` isn't on CTAN yet, I have to make language detection more robust, so you can download it from github and install in to your local `TEXMFHOME` dir if you want to use it.

Comment: It looks great! Is there a possibility to set an exception, something similar to `\mbox{one two}` when dealing with hyphenation?

Comment: @Malipivo do you mean possibility to prohibit processing of text in command argument, or possibility to exclude certain letters from processing?

Comment: My question is close to the first option, if there is an option of turning process on and off directly in document, if needed. I think that we usually wish to process "Ch. Somebody" no matter of language we actually use, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Malipivo I added new command `\preventsinglelang` for using only one language settings for whole document, if one wants this behaviour

Comment: That's excellent, you are fast!

Comment: @Malipivo I've added also commands for turning on/off the processing: `\preventsingleon` and `\preventsingleoff`

Comment: Good job! I think we are done with this task.

Comment: @Malipivo I hope so :) now I have to find how to support languages in formats which doesn't use `languages.dat` (like `csplain`) and the work is done

Comment: What about if you try parsing a `log` file from the previous run of TeX? `:-)` I guess there are better ways to figure it out...

Comment: @Malipivo but you cannot read log file while luatex compilation is running :( but I have problem only with csplain, parsing of `language.dat` does work in other cases

Comment: @Malipivo I just added support for csplain, I extracted language codes and numbers from `hyphen.lan` file and then replaced language codes with names used in babel

Comment: That's a good news, well done!

Answer (score 2):

EDITED to catch more cases (and examine failure modes)

I concur with David's recommendation not to make the space active. So the approach I take here is to make the dot active, with the ability to turn the feature on (`\initialsON`) and off (`\initialsOFF`) as needed, if it is found to interfere with something else.

The choice of an active dot will bring with it a severe limitation, we will find, in that an active dot occurs *after* the initialed letter, and so it becomes impossible to definitively know if an initial preceded the active dot.  But we can nonetheless make interesting progress towards that goal.

With my original solution (the path that follows `\specdothelper`), the detection scheme was only triggered on initials typed without spaces, such as `J.W.Bush`, such that it converted a sequence `.X` into `.~X` if there was no space between the `.` and the `X`, where `X` represents any capital letter.  This compressed syntax may take a little getting used to or even be outright unacceptable to many users.

With this latest REVISION (and my first successful use of `\futurelet`, *yippee*), I now also can search for the syntax `. X.`, where there is a space after the first dot, then a capital letter followed by a dot.  If this sequence is found, it is converted into `.~X.`  And if and only if initials have been lately found, the sequence `. Xx` will assume the last name has been located and convert it to `.~Xx`.  Thus, in a sequence like `J. Z. A. Bush`, it will catch all three spaces, converting them into hard spaces.

By using the dot as the active character, however, I am prevented from knowing whether the character prior to the dot was an initial, and can only try to discern it by looking forward in the input stream.  In the example given by `G. Washington`, the problem with the first dot is that, without a pattern of initials already being established, the forward-looking `. Wa` set of characters could be the beginning of a sentence rather than a name following the initial.  And so this important case is missed.

In this EDIT, I've reduced the discussion hereafter on the guts of the logic.  I'll only summarize and say that the challenge areas were spaces, `\par`s, and repeated dots `..` (since dots are active characters), which required special treatment.  Also, the new logic with this revision follows the `\foundspace` macro.

Places where the compressed (no-space) syntax will fail are shown in my MWE.  If a last name does not begin with a capital is one case, such as C.deLune.  Also, if a url has a dot followed by a capital letter, this would cause a space to be inserted (though `\initialsOFF` should be used before setting such unconventional text as url's).

When employing the revised syntax where spaces remain between the initials in your LaTeX file, there are three known failure modes (one of them crucial).  The first, discussed above at some length, is the case of a single initial followed by a last name.  The  second failure is when a sentence starts with an initial (though this is bad grammar).  The third case of failure is when a sentence ends in what looks like initials, such as `U. S. A.`  In this case, the first word of the next sentence is perceived as the last name, and a hard space is inserted.

When using the compressed syntax, the requirement to enter initials without spaces in your document may be wholly unacceptable to many users.  And in the normal expanded syntax, the inabilty to detect a lone initial in a sequence greatly limits the usefulness of this approach.

In the MWE that follows, I have purposely defined my hard space `\HS` as a `\rule` to make it visible.  To use this code in its intended way, that definition should be replaced with the one that defines it as a hard space (or a skinny space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifnextok}
\def\HS{\rule{.66ex}{1ex}}% TO DEMONSTRATE WHERE ACTIVE
%\def\HS{\,}% FOR NARROW SPACE
%\def\HS{~}% FOR NORMAL HARD SPACE
\let\svdot.
\def\knowninit{F}
\makeatletter
\def\specdot{\svdot\IfNextToken\@sptoken{\foundspace}%
  {\gdef\knowninit{F}\specdothelper}}
\long\def\foundspace#1{\IfNextToken\@sptoken{ #1\gdef\knowninit{F}}%
  {\def\savefirst{#1}\lookatsecond}}
\def\lookatsecond{\futurelet\secondchar\processsecond}

\long\def\specdothelper#1{%
  \if\svdot#1%
    \svdot%
  \else%
    \ifx#1\par%
      \par%
    \else%
      \ifnum`#1>`@\ifnum`#1<`[\HS\fi\fi#1%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\catcode`.=\active
\def\processsecond{%
  \ifx\secondchar.%
    \HS\gdef\knowninit{T}%
  \else%
    \if T\knowninit%
      \ifnum\expandafter`\savefirst>`@\ifnum\expandafter`\savefirst<`[\HS\else%
        { }\fi\else{ }\fi%
    \else%
      { }%
    \fi%
    \gdef\knowninit{F}%
  \fi%
  \savefirst%
}
\def\initialsON{\catcode`.=\active\def.{\specdot}}
\def\initialsOFF{\catcode`.=12\let.\svdot}
\catcode`.=12
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\noindent ON\initialsON

Fully spaced initials J. Z. A. Bush being tested, and here we check double and single initials: 
J. Q. Adams and G. Washington.  A single initial cannot be discerned because the dot after 
the G cannot know if the prior letter is an initial and no other initials follow the dot.

U. S. A. is OK, since ``is'' is not capitalized.

We can be fooled by U. S. Olympic Team, in that it considers ``Olympic'' to be the last name.
Can also be fooled if sentence ends in the U. S. A. The new sentence starts with a hard-space, 
with ``The'' as the last name.  Leaving out the spaces will fix U.S.A.  If no spaces are wanted,
\initialsOFF U.S.A. \initialsON 
can be gotten by temporarily turning initials OFF.

Compressed or uncompressed C.deLune and  C. de Lune fail to insert a hard space, because 
``d'' is not a capital letter.

Unspaced combinations: 3.2, a.b, J.Z.A.Bush, and G.Washington being successfully tested
 here, with non-capital letters screened out.

Testing.. successive... dots is OK... Unless the sentence ends with odd number of dots, then 
a space immediately followed by a dotted initial... S. Segletes would never start a sentence 
with an initial.  It is poor grammar in the first place. 

\noindent\hrulefill\\
OFF\initialsOFF (This was the raw text being processed)

Fully spaced initials J. Z. A. Bush being tested, and here we check double and single initials: 
J. Q. Adams and G. Washington.  A single initial cannot be discerned because the dot after 
the G cannot know if the prior letter is an initial and no other initials follow the dot.

U. S. A. is OK, since ``is'' is not capitalized.

We can be fooled by U. S. Olympic Team, in that it considers ``Olympic'' to be the last name.
Can also be fooled if sentence ends in the U. S. A. The new sentence starts with a hard-space, 
with ``The'' as the last name.  Leaving out the spaces will fix U.S.A.  If no spaces are wanted,
U.S.A. 
can be gotten by temporarily turning initials OFF.

Compressed or uncompressed C.deLune and  C. de Lune fail to insert a hard space, because 
``d'' is not a capital letter.

Unspaced combinations: 3.2, a.b, J.Z.A.Bush, and G.Washington being successfully tested
 here, with non-capital letters screened out.

Testing.. successive... dots is OK... Unless the sentence ends with odd number of dots, then 
a space immediately followed by a dotted initial... S. Segletes would never start a sentence 
with an initial.  It is poor grammar in the first place. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These ideas are inspiring!

Comment: @Malipivo I realize "inspiring" is a polite way of saying "thanks for trying" 8^)  I just wanted you to know I've made some additional progress, but flaws remain.  But it has been an interesting exercise for me.  Thanks for the challenge.  I wonder how the lua solution performs on some of my problem situations, like `as seen in the U. S. The next sentence` or `sentence is done. S. Segletes starts the next sentence` or `C. deLune` or `U. S. Olympic Team`?

Comment: It was my first bounty, I am still looking for a way how I could split the points. I owe you one. Yes, that's the reason I was looking for adding a list of exceptions or a way how to turn on and off the process, there are many more examples: `V. van Gogh`, `L. van Beethoven`, `J. von Mises`, `Ch. A. J. M. de Gaulle`, `L. da Vinci`. I believe that processing TeX/Bib file externally (as program `vlna` does) is the best way. We would not touch the original file (then we could process HTML/JS or other files by changing one letter `~`->`&nbsp;`) and there would be a chance to make a backup.