# space before and after emdashes

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I am typing a document in French and I need to automatically get a fine space (unbreakable) after opening emdash and before closing dash.
`---\, blahblah\, ---` is not very good...

How can I do that.

Best,
Fred

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=26894)

Comment: Depending on what `blahblah` semantically is supposed to mean I'd define a new macro or environment `\newcommand\thought[1]{---\,#1\,---}` and then use `\thought{blahblah}`

Comment: BTW: the example in your post has thin spaces *in addition* to normal ones…

Comment: Doesn't `frenchb` ensure this automatically?

Comment: You can adapt the code from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/disallowing-line-break-before-dash-en-dash-and-em-dash/22423#22423

Answer (score 2):

You can use LaTeX unbreakable space `~`:

```
~-~Blahblah~-~
```

This will create a space and force the TeX engine to link the part before and after the tilde to be on the same line of text produced.

You can create a command to not type them:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{~-~}
```

For a thin space you can use `\,` without space around:

```
\,-\,Blahblah\,-\,
```

With `newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\bar}{\,-\,}
```

Comment: Thanks.But ~ generates a normal space, not a thin one...

Comment: @Fred_O see my edit for a thin space.

Comment: isn't it usual to use an en-dash (`--`) rather than a hyphen between the spaces?